# Parameter value [1410] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a method in JPA repository that takes Set as an argument which I am having an Integer to be passed which I have to convert into Long and then add it to a Set and pass it to the method.

After doing these steps I am getting InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [1410] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)] Exception.

My Repository method:

```
  @Query("select detail from #{#entityName} detail"
      + " WHERE " + " detail.master.id = :masterId"
      + " and detail.product = :product and detail.llMERestrictedProviders in :providerId"
     )
 Optional<List<BlackholeDetailEntity>> findByProductLLME(@Param("product") ProductType product,
      @Param("masterId") Long masterId, @Param("providerId") Set<Long> providerId);
```

My calling Code:

```
Set<Long> providers = new HashSet<Long>();
      providers.add(new Long(pricingCopyRequestBO.getProviderId()));

        blackholeOfferlist =
            blackholeDetailRepository.findByProductLLME(pricingCopyRequestBO.getProductType(),
                pricingCopyRequestBO.getSourcePolygonId(), providers);
```

I have tried Long.valueof(pricingCopyRequestBO.getProviderId()) as well

Comment: You might not need this `@Query` if you name your method using the `In` keyword it might work for you. Here's a link for you to use as reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185266/springdata-jpa-hibernate-collection-for-in-keyword?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: `detail.llMERestrictedProviders` is this a related entity or just an id field

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Did you make any progress?  I had no problem with the query using the method name query approach, but when my query became too complex I converted to @Query and now get the exact same error you are getting.

Comment: @Vishnu detail.llMERestrictedProviders is Set<Long>.

Comment: how is `detail.llMERestrictedProviders` stored in your database, does it have its own table?